# Why isn't my function defined after I execute its JS file and I cant pass in variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Please review my chrome extension code, that I think is well commented enough to understand.When context menu item "add term" is selected in the context of highlighted text, the text is copied then accessed and should pop up on the side bar.

error Failed to copy text: ReferenceError: copyToClipboard is not defined

- also text variable doesnt get passed in

*Note to stack overflow reviewer, this question is not like associated because my script is being executed from a separate script.

**service-worker.js**

}

```
// when "addterm" is clicked sequence of functions to be called and sidepanel.js is injected, 
// then side panel is opened.
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    if (info.menuItemId === "addterm") {

        // selection test is passed to global variable 'text'
        text = info.selectionText;
        console.log(text);
        // The example will show how data can be copied, but since background
        // pages cannot directly write to the clipboard, we will run a content
        // script that copies the actual content.

        // first dingo() function is  run to check if copyToClipboard() is defined.
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: {
              tabId: tab.id,
            },
            func: dingo
        }).then((results) => {
            // if results[0].result is not true then copyToClipboard() is not defined 
            // and sidepanel.js should be injected in current tab
            if (!results || results[0].result !== true) {
                console.log(results[0].result)
                return chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                    target: {tabId: tab.id},
                    files: ["sidepanel.js"]
                });
            }
        // then function to copy 'text' is supposed to run but for some reason throws not defined error. 
        }).then(() => {
            return chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target:{tabId:tab.id},
                func: copyToClipboard(),
                args: [text]
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            // This could happen if the extension is not allowed to run code in
            // the page, for example if the tab is a privileged page.
            console.error("Failed to copy text: " + error);
        })
    chrome.sidePanel.open({windowId: tab.windowId});
    }
});
```

**sidepanel.js**

```
console.log("hi") // declares variable that is  supposed to to be set equal to text that is copied. var paragraph = document.getElementById("p"); // This function must be called in a visible page, such as a browserAction popup // or a content script. Calling it in a background page has no effect!

function copyToClipboard(text) {
    function oncopy(event) {
        document.removeEventListener("copy", oncopy, true);
        // Hide the event from the page to prevent tampering.
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        // supposed to get data from clipboard and set equal to html element on sidebar.
        event.preventDefault();
        data = event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain", text )
        console.log(data)
        paragraph.textContent += data;
        console.log("hi")
    }
    document.addEventListener("copy", oncopy, true);
    console.log("hi")
    console.log(text)
    // copies 'text' to clipboard
    document.execCommand('copy', false, text); }
```

**sidepanel.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Sidepanel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>All sites sidepanel extension</h1>
    <p id="p">text</p>
    <button id="btn">Change specialkeys</button>
    <script src="sidepanel.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of copyToClipboard function use `document.execCommand('copy', false, text)` where text is passed via `args` parameter of executeScript.

Comment: tried that out out still didn't work

Comment: Remove `()` in `func: copyToClipboard()`, remove executeScript for sidepanel.js (it runs in the side panel, not in the web page), remove everything inside copyToClipboard except document.execCommand line and copy this function into your background script.